# How to enforce Django to use "JOIN VALUES"

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm having a performance problem where I need to replace section of my query statement. Right now I have a the following:

```
select count(*) FROM "mytable" WHERE "field" IN ('v1', 'v2', ..., 'vN');
```

this can be translated to Django ORM:

```
Mytable.objects.all().filter(field__in=[myvalues]).count()
```

I need to do the following though:

```
select count(*) FROM "mytable" JOIN (values ('v1', 'v2', ..., 'vN')) as lookup(value) on lookup.value = "mytable".field;
```

Is there a way to add this to the ORM? I need to do with ORM because I already have other filters. Worst case scenario I thought of getting the query string and adding there manually...

I'm using Postgresql 9.6

Comment: I would find it rather weird that this would really boost performance (significantly)...

Comment: It does a lot... if I add 10k records in the myvalues filter takes more than minutes. With the join takes miliseconds

Comment: ah... the dimension was not really clear :)

Comment: A CTE along with [django-cte](https://github.com/dimagi/django-cte) could be helpful here, but without knowing more about the specifics (type of DB, kind of lookup data etc) it's really just guessing

Comment: where are you getting the list of values? it might help to have them stored in your database rather then stuck into your code...purgatory is troubleshooting someone else's code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way after reading over and over the documentation. I even found [a patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7231#no1) that was not merged a while ago.

It doesn't really do the join, but it works much faster than using `__in` straightforward.

What I'm doing is executing a RawSQL() that was introduced in Django 2.0 and with that result I do the `__in` again.

So here is a code example:

```
query = """select myfield from mytable join (values 
             ('v1'), ('v2'), ..., ('vN')
           ) as lookup(value) on lookup.value = mytable.myfield"""
r = RawSQL(query, [])
mymodel.filter(myfield__in=r)
```

**Now it takes miliseconds instead of minutes!**